# How To Use Methods With Array In Java?

Tags: java, arrays

My first question here so please point out my mistakes. And to be honest I couldn't find any similar questions.

So I am trying to write something very basic and I really can't figure why I can't call a method from my Util Class in my Main class.

**Util class**

```
    private double accumulatedArea;
    private double accumulatedCircumference;


    public static double getAccumulatedArea(Shape[] shapes) {
        double accumulatedArea = 0;
        for (Shape s : shapes) {
            accumulatedArea = accumulatedArea + s.area();
            return accumulatedArea;
        }
        return accumulatedArea;
    }


    public static double getAccumulatedCircumference(Shape[] shapes) {
        double accumulatedCircumference = 0;
        for (Shape q : shapes) {
            accumulatedCircumference = accumulatedCircumference + q.circumference();
            return accumulatedCircumference;
        }
        return accumulatedCircumference;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Number: ";
     }

}
```

and **Main class**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Shape[] shapes = new Shape[4];

        shapes[0] = new Circle(100);
        shapes[1] = new Circle(23);

        shapes[2] = new Rectangle(10, 20);
        shapes[3] = new Rectangle(8, 12);

        System.out.println("Area of the circle 1: " + shapes[0].area() + " and its circumference is: " + shapes[0].circumference());
        System.out.println("Area of the circle 2: " + shapes[1].area() + " and its circumference is: " + shapes[1].circumference());

        System.out.println("Area of the rectangle 1: " + shapes[2].area() + " and its circumference is: " + shapes[2].circumference());
        System.out.println("Area of the rectangle 2: " + shapes[3].area() + " and its circumference is: " + shapes[3].circumference());
        //Small test
        System.out.println("Number of shapes are in the system: " + shapes.length);

        //????? What to do here??
        for (int p = 0; p < shapes.length; p++) {
            Shape[p].getAccumulatedArea();
        }


    }
}
```

How can I call my `getAccumulatedArea` and `getAccumulatedCircumference` methods??

Been searching for couple of days now and I really don't have any idea how.

Just in case there is also 2 Rectangle and Circle classes that I use. They are very similar so I am only putting one.

```
    private double radius;
    private double circumference;
    private double area;
    private ArrayList<Circle> circles;


    //throws Exception gives error! learn how to do exceptions!
    public Circle(double radius) {
        super();
        if(radius > 0) {
            this.radius = radius;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Throw new Exception!!");
        }
    }

    public void setRadius(double radius) throws Exception {
        if (radius < 0) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        else {
            this.radius = radius;
        }
    }
    public void setCircumference(double circumference) throws Exception {
        if (circumference < 0) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        else {
            this.circumference = circumference;
        }
    }

    public void setArea(double area) {
        if (area <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please check your input!");
        }
        else {
            this.area = area;
        }
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public double getCircumference() throws Exception{
        if (radius < 0) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        else {
            return circumference;
        }
    }

    public double getArea() throws Exception{
        if (radius < 0) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        else {
            return area;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public double circumference() {
        return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    }

    @Override
    public double area() {
        return radius * radius * Math.PI;
    }
}
```

The code seems kinda messy but that's because I've been trying everything :) Any advice is welcome. Btw I was using Arraylist but according to some people I know, using Array is much better in this circumstance.

Comment: `double result = Util.getAccumulatedArea(shapes);` instead of a loop with `Shape[p].getAccumulatedArea();` in the body. An array is just a variable, which you can pass to a method in the same way as any other variable. Look at the `getAccumulatedArea` method. It expects you to pass an array of `Shape` objects as an argument.

Comment: Please don't listen to those "some people". While learning, use `ArrayList`, it's much easier to work with.

Comment: Note that `Util.getAccumluatedArea(Shape[])` should not have a `return` inside the loop.  This will result in returning the area of the first Shape in the array rather than the sum of the areas of all the Shapes in that array.

Comment: Thank you all finally figurued it out thanks to you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods in your `Util` class are `static`. A static method should be invoked on the *class* it is declared as part of. Both of your methods you have declared to take a parameter of type `Shape[]`. So you should invoke them like so:

```
Util.getAccumulatedArea(shapes)
```

…where `shapes` is a value of type `Shape[]`.